# Using a for loop to insert a value into a tkinter entry field

Tags: tkinter

I'm working on building a simple tkinter password program and I'm running into a problem.  I get the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "password.py", line 23, in pass_gen
    PassField.insert(0, random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_letters), end='')
TypeError: insert() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end'
```

If I delete **end=''** the error message will go away but the code doesn't function as expected.  I end up getting a single digit password instead of the desired length.

```
import random
import string

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
strength = IntVar()
length = DoubleVar()
root.title('Password Generator')

def pass_gen(event):
    lengthy = int(PassLength.get())
    print(lengthy)
    if strength.get() == 1:
        for i in range(0, lengthy):
            PassField.delete(0, 'end')
            PassField.insert(0, random.choice(string.ascii_letters), end='')

    elif strength.get() == 2:
        for i in range(0, lengthy):
            PassField.delete(0, 'end')
            PassField.insert(0, random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_letters), end='')

    elif strength == 'x':
        for i in range(0, lengthy):
            PassField.delete(0, 'end')
            PassField.insert(0, random.choice(string.punctuation + string.digits + string.ascii_letters), end='')


Radiobutton(root, text="Weak", variable=strength, value=1).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
Radiobutton(root, text="Strong", variable=strength, value=2).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
Radiobutton(root, text="Extra-strong", variable=strength, value=3).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)

Label(root, text='Length').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
PassLength = Scale(root, variable=length, from_=0, to=30,  orient=HORIZONTAL)
PassLength.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label(root, text='Password').grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx=4)
PassField = Entry(root)
PassField.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

generateButton = Button(root, text='Generate')
generateButton.bind("<Button-1>", pass_gen)
generateButton.grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

I'd appreciate your input.  TIA

Comment: What do you expect `end=''` to do?  Also, you are explicitly deleting the contents each time through the loop. Why are you doing that?

Comment: After some experimenting I know what my problem is.  Don't know how to fix it.  I was using end='' hoping it would concatenate the individual characters in the password into the selected length.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `insert('end', ...)`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

p = tk.Entry(root)
p.pack()

p.insert(0, 'a')
p.insert('end', 'b')

root.mainloop()
```

But remove `delete(0, 'end')` because you delete provious data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the proper way to concatenate the password, here is my updated code:

```
import random
import string

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
strength = IntVar()
length = DoubleVar()
root.title('Password Generator')
def pass_gen(event):
    lengthy = int(PassLength.get())

    if strength.get() == 1:
        list = []
        for i in range(0, lengthy):
            list.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
            password = ''.join(list)
            PassField.delete(0, 'end')
            PassField.insert(0, password)

    elif strength.get() == 2:
        list = []
        for i in range(0, lengthy):
            list.append(random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_letters))
            password = ''.join(list)
            PassField.delete(0, 'end')
            PassField.insert(0, password)

    elif strength.get() == 3:
        list = []
        for i in range(0, lengthy):
            list.append(random.choice(string.punctuation + string.digits + string.ascii_letters))
            password = ''.join(list)
            PassField.delete(0, 'end')
            PassField.insert(0, password)


Radiobutton(root, text="Weak", variable=strength, value=1).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
Radiobutton(root, text="Strong", variable=strength, value=2).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
Radiobutton(root, text="Extra-strong", variable=strength, value=3).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)

Label(root, text='Length').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
PassLength = Scale(root, variable=length, from_=0, to=20,  orient=HORIZONTAL)
PassLength.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label(root, text='Password').grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx=4)
PassField = Entry(root)
PassField.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

generateButton = Button(root, text='Generate')
generateButton.bind("<Button-1>", pass_gen)
generateButton.grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```